# default multiple rows in a gridview using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want multiple rows default in a gridview..
but i have a code like,

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <FooterTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" />
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

after click "Add New Row" button in .cs file ,

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddNewRowToGrid();
}

 private void AddNewRowToGrid()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //extract the TextBox values
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                rowIndex++;
            }
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

            Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }

    //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
    SetPreviousData();
}
```

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control-with-TextBoxes.aspx
here only 1 row is there default, but i need atleast 4 rows,
then how to save that in db too.
help...

Comment: `here only 1 row is there default, but i need atleast 4 rows`

Sorry what means it ?

Comment: above coding im having single row as textboxes.. but i need multiple rows ...

Comment: When ? It want to on-load event or when click a button \ ? and what is the `dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count` value ?

Comment: i need default .... not to click another button......